# Compact space with $x_{n_j} \to x $ for all conv. subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Given a compact metric space $(X,d)$ with sequence $(x_n)_n \subseteq X$ and every convergent subsequence of $(x_n)_n$ converges against $x$. 
How can I show that $x_n \to x$? 
Hints are welcome!

> I just tried this: If for $\underline{all}$ subsequences $(x_{n_j})_j$ comes true that $x_{n_j}\to x$, we are done. So, lets say, there are the subsequences $(x_{n_{j_1}})_{j_1}, \dots ,(x_{n_{j_m}})_{j_m}, \dots$. Then we have $\varepsilon_{j_1}>0, \dots , \varepsilon_{j_m}>0, \dots$ that for all $n\geq N(\varepsilon_{j_1}), \dots$ we get $d(x,x_n)<\varepsilon_{j_1}$ and so on. If we take the maximum of all these $N(\varepsilon)$'s - let us call it $N_M$ we further get for all subsequences: $d(x,x_n) < \varepsilon \ \forall n\geq N_M$. Now I tried to split $d(x,x_n)$ by using the triangle inequality, but there are still elements of $(x_n)_n$, which I don't get. I just know that the distance is bounded, but I am not able to make it arbitrarily small.

Comment: Suppose the sequence did not converge to $x$. Then there would be an $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $x_{n_k}$, such that ...

Answer (score 1):

If $x_n$ does not converge to $x$, then you would negate the definition of $x_n \to x$ : ie. There would exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $n_k > k$ such that
$$
x_{n_k} \notin B(x,\epsilon)
$$
Now you need to tweak this a little to get a bonafide subsequence (why?)